# How to create simple linear prediction model in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, model, linear-regression

Lately I am trying to create an interactive shiny app. In this app I want a linear model to predict a given value by the user. Also, the predictor and explanatory variable can be selected by the user. After this, the model simply returns the predicted value displayed by the app. However, I cannot figure out how to let the app use an existing data frame and return the predicted value. When running the app I get the following error:

```
Warning in storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning: Error in contrasts<-: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
[No stack trace available]
```

The script itself is similar to the code by Sean Kross (https://seankross.com/developing-data-products/shiny.html#reactivity). I used the script presented below resulting in the error:

```
librar(shiny)
#Create random data frame with three vectors
df          <- data.frame(V1=1:100, V2=100:1*runif(100, min=0, max=1), V3=1:100*runif(100, min=0, max=1))

ui          <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Regression"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    p("Select explanatory variable"),
    selectInput(inputId = "ExpVar", label = "Explanatory variable", choices = colnames(df)),
    p("Select predictor variable"),
    selectInput(inputId = "PreVar", label = "Predictor variable", choices = colnames(df)), 
    numericInput(inputId = "Pred", label = "Predict chosen value", value = 10),
    h3("Prediction"),
    textOutput("prediction")))

server      <- function(input, output){

    modpred <- reactive({
    Pre     <- input$Pred
    Pname   <- input$PreVar
    mod     <- lm(input$PreVar~input$ExpVar, data=df)
    predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(Pname = Pre))})

    output$prediction <- renderText({modpred()})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be different approaches for this. One might be to use `varSelectInput` and select variable names from `df` in your `ui` (this returns a symbol).

Here we leave the `selectInput` and use the character strings. Before using `lm`, you will need to create a formulate based on these character strings, as they are not symbols.

To do this, you can use `as.formula` or `reformulate` (the latter done here). This will generate your formula (e.g., `V2 ~ V1`).

In addition, for `predict` you will want the column name of the `new_df` to be set to whatever `Pname` is. The previous code would name the column itself `Pname`, instead of the string that `Pname` is equal to.

```
modpred <- reactive({
  Pre     <- input$Pred
  Pname   <- input$PreVar
  mod     <- lm(reformulate(input$PreVar, input$ExpVar), data=df)
  new_df  <- data.frame(Pre)
  names(new_df) <- Pname
  predict(mod, newdata = new_df)
})
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you!! It is confusing to me that the input/output is not defined outside the server function. The use of the reactive function is also different to normal R functions. The shiny website gives some examples, but most are extremely focused on the display of plots, not simple examples of model predictions. Does anyone have some recommendation on simple examples of models applied in shiny?